# Calculate offset coordinate in a cartesian space

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry, cartesian

if I have 2 coordinate pointA(x,y) and pointB(x,y)

I need to calculate the offset coordinate at specific distance and angle 90 deg and 270 deg.
How can I?

Can't find the right formula.

How to get the coordinate of C,D,E,F?

[image: pic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference vector

```
dx = B.X - A.X
dy = B.Y - A.Y
```

Perpendicular vector

```
px = -dy
py = dx
```

Vector length (perhaps you have ready function `Hypot` or alike function in your math library)

```
len = sqrt(px*px+py*py)
```

Normalized (unit length) vector

```
nx = px / len
ny = py / len
```

Now find points at distance `dist`:

```
C.X = A.X + nx * dist
C.Y = A.Y + nY * dist

G.X = A.X - nx * dist
G.Y = A.Y - nY * dist
```

similar for points around B